# Estrutura de repetição em R

Tags: r

Não estou conseguindo uma lógica para fazer o seguinte problema em estrutura de repetição:

Tenho um vetor A com 1 elemento e outro B com 30 elementos. Queria subtrair o vetor A de cada elemento de B de modo que essa subtração fosse acumulada, por exemplo:

```
A=50
B=c(7,6,7,6,5,6,7,5,6,7)

#subtracao
50-7=43;

43-6=37;

37-7=30;
```

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cumsum` é o mais facil neste problema

```
> A=50
> B=c(7,6,7,6,5,6,7,5,6,7)
> cumsum(B)
 [1]  7 13 20 26 31 37 44 49 55 62
> A-cumsum(B)
 [1]  43  37  30  24  19  13   6   1  -5 -12
```